# How to import a schema.prisma file inside another?

Tags: prisma

One of my schema.prisma's file is wrote like this:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/own_database"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Employee {
  ...
}
```

And I have another one, which is like this:

```
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    output   = "./generated/another_database"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL_2")
}

model Costs {
    cod_center_cost Int      @id
    description String?  @db.VarChar(100)
    status           Boolean?
    classification Int?
}

...
```

I have a model that needs to have a relation to another model, but how can I refer an another file's model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Splitting Prisma's schema file is not officially possible yet.

However there are some community provided solutions like [Aurora](https://github.com/sabinadams/aurora) which provides you functionality to split prisma schemas and import them.

Here's the Official [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2377) where splitting schema file is being tracked by Prisma Team.